# How to Send SMS using AWS SNS in JavaScript for exceeding characters

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

AWS SNS to Send SMS in JavaScript wouldn't work after 160 characters. How to resolve this issue ? Using library aws-sdk

Answer (score 0):

From [What is the SMS Character Limit? - Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-sms-character-limit):

> The character limit for a single SMS message is 160 characters, however most modern phones and networks support concatenation and segment and rebuild messages up to 1600 characters.

So, the limit you are hitting is inherent in the design of SMS. That's also why Twitter limited tweets to 140 characters (more recently, double that).